# Clarification on index reduction on non-linear implicit DAEs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of DAEs (4 ODEs and one algebraic constraint) of index 2 given by the following (I'm excluding the first three ODE's as they don't have a direct effect on the index of the DAE):

$$X4' = \frac{1}{t*X4}\left(\frac{PUr}{t*X1}\frac{X1 - X4}{|X1 - X4|}\left(1 + \frac16\left(|X1 - X4|G\right)^\frac23\right) + Ve^2 - X4^2\right)$$

$$Ve = \sin\theta\left(0.5*t*X4' + X4\right)$$

$$Ur = \left((X1 - X4)^2 + (X2 - Ve*\cos\theta)^2 + X3^2\right)^{1/2}$$

This is an index 2 DAE, however, if X4' is substituted in the equation for Ve, then an index 1 system is achieved without any differentiation. The following gives the modified algebraic equation for Ve:

$$Ve - \frac{\sin\theta}{2X4}\left(\frac{PUr}{tX1}\frac{X1 - X4}{|X1 - X4|}\left(1 + \frac16\left(|X1 - X4|*G\right)^\frac23\right) + Ve^2 + X4^2\right) = 0$$

Am I correct in my calculation of the index? I know differentiation has the potential to significantly alter the behavior of the DAE (in that it can introduce many more solutions outside the DAE manifold), however, will index reduction through substitution introduce similar errors?

Also, I tried making my equations look better by formatting them. If they don't show up properly, give me a sec and I'll try to figure it out.

I should add that $\theta$, G, and P are constants. And that the absolute values are there for correctness of the equation, but applying the equations will yield X1 to be always greater than X4 so that the ODE is smooth (no sign changes).